# How can I change multiple MySQL rows in a table with Doctrine_Query?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

so I'm trying to change some specific columns in a row in a table of a MySQL database by calling the Doctrine_Query when an option is selected inside an admin panel of my website.

Here are the details:

- Table name: chatUsers
- I need to find all rows with the person who has
  a username of: $chatUsers->username (The column inside chatUsers is
  called username)
- Once all those rows are found, change the value of all the row's column "type" to "user"

Is this even possible?

So far I have:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('db_chatUsers')->where('username = $chatUsers->username')->findAll();
```

...And I'm not sure where to go from there, or if that's even correct. I probably have to use 'foreach' or something. Sorry in advance, I'm not very good with PHP yet.

Answer (score 0):

I  just pulled it off from http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language

i've never used doctrine and i have no idea if this works.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('db_chatUsers')
    ->set('type', '?', 'user');
    ->where('username = '.$chatUsers->username);

// If the "user" is column not a value then use instead:
//$query->set('type', 'user');

//execute query
$rows = $query->execute();
echo $rows.' rows updated';
```